# How to remove new Line in Java

Tags: java

Below You Can see Output of My Program I want to end my program on line no. 7 How Can i Achieve i spent 1 hours but still not able to solve this problem. I saw multiple solution but all are same type the are getting the correct output.
**Note: - Main method should not alter any line of code**

[image]

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Person {
        private int age;    

        public Person(int initialAge) {
            age = initialAge;
            if (age < 0) {
               age = 0;
                System.out.println("Age is Not Valid, Setting age to 0");
            }
        }

       private void amIOld() {
            String s = "";
            if (age < 13) {
                s = "You are Young";
            } else if (age >= 13 && age < 18) {
                s = "Your are Teenager";
            } else {
                s = "You are Old";
            }
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    private void yearPasses() {
        age++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            Person p = new Person(age);
            p.amIOld();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                p.yearPasses();
            }
            p.amIOld();
            System.out.println();
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.exit(0);` on the line where you want to terminate the program.
Here is the link where you can learn more:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-exit-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

I understood what your problem is above question is part of Hackerank 30 days of code java challenge, and the problem your code won't be accepted has nothing to do with the new line. In your constructor just change the line `age to 0` to `age to 0.` and it will work.

You have not added the dot after 0 in print statement is the issue.